# Django, user confirmation with try and except

Tags: python, django

I am facing an error with a function that needs the confirmation that a user is there.
Here is the code in views.py:

Imports:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

The view:

```
def (enclosed)View(request, creator_username):
    try:
        creator = get_object_or_404(User, username=creator_username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        messages.error(request, "Creator not found.")
        return redirect("homepage")  # Redirect to some error page or homepage
```

The error:

```
Class 'User' has no 'DoesNotExist' member
```

I have tried adding the "get_object_or_404" but it still doesn't work.
I don't know any other way to get it to work.

Comment: Are you reassigning the identifier `User` a different value somewhere between your imports and this view? Maybe you have another view called `User` above this one?

Comment: @user2390182. No, I don't have a view with that name. Only that I'm using the import User in other views above.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the function get_object_or_404() does not return this error,
it either return Http404 or ValueError

So, in this case what you can do is:

```
from django.http.response import Http404 # Importing the required error it raises
def (enclosed)View(request, creator_username):
    try:
        creator = get_object_or_404(User, username=creator_username)
    except (ValueError, Http404): # Checking if any of the two are sent back
        messages.error(request, "Creator not found.")
        return redirect("homepage")  # Redirect to some error page or homepage
```

Documentation [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) of the function, there is note where it says that it returns a Http404 object and not DoesNotExists

Comment: Thank you! This worked. There is no error anymore. I couldn't have figured this out.